# MYSQL - ORDER BY Numeric column with parenthesis

Tags: mysql

I have an old database with a list of books. Each book has a volume number. The volumes can be part 1 and part 2. So, I have books with these volume numbers:

```
1
2
3
...
29 (1)
29 (2)
30 (1)
30 (2)
```

I need to select all volumes in DESC order, ordering by the volume number column. Originally I did this dynamic casting:

```
SELECT * FROM volumenes ORDER BY volumen_numero * 1 DESC
```

Which worked *great* until it reached 30! For some reason, it now returns this:

```
30 (1)
30 (2)
29 (2)
29 (1)
... all sorted correctly from this point on
```

I tried replacing the parenthesis from the column value, like so:

```
ORDER BY CAST(replace(replace(volumen_numero,")",""), "(", "") as unsigned)
```

But I get the exact same result.

What I'm looking for is this order:

```
30 (2)
30 (1)
29 (2)
29 (1)
...
```

[Here you have a working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25de4/5)

Comment: this is what comes of bad database design. put a new "volume" field into your table, and your query becomes `order by book, volume`.

Comment: I understand that the design is bad. Adding a proper column would mean that I would have to manually add this new value for each book. I'd rather find a better query.

Comment: "I have a bad design. I need to make an even worse query to cover it up" is exactly the WRONG response. you fix your table once, the problem is gone forever. You write one bad query, you'll have to write **MORE** bad queries later when your requirements change.

Comment: You would not have to do it manually, one can write a query do fill the column or do it programmatically with a simple regex expression

Comment: Well sure, you have convinced me. I'll add an INT column with the volume number like so: 1, 2, ..., 291, 292, 301, 302. The old column needs to stay because it's the one showed in the frontend.

Comment: I would still like an answer to this problem. How come it worked until 30? What are those string values being converted to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only sorting by the first number.  Here is a more explicit approach:

```
order by substring_index(volumen_numero, ' ', 1) + 0,
         substring_index(volumen_numero, ' ', -1)
```

The above will work as long as the volume number is one digit.  You can handle longer volume numbers with:

```
order by substring_index(volumen_numero, ' ', 1) + 0,
         length(substring_index(volumen_numero, ' ', -1)),
         substring_index(volumen_numero, ' ', -1)
```

Or, if you prefer being cryptic and shorter:

```
order by volumen_numero + 0,
         substring_index(volumen_numero, '(', -1) + 0
```

Comment: I like these. I'll add a new int column to handle this properly though. If no better answers come along I'll mark yours because it's the cleanest one so far. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/453d52/5

Answer (score 1):

You should debug in your select what happens.
(Add the order expression to the select and verify it.)

I guess the space disturbs the integer conversion. (Probably the second part will be truncated.)
If this assumption is true, you can fix it easily:

```
ORDER BY CAST(replace(replace(replace(volumen_numero,")",""), "(", "")," ","") as unsigned)
```

Comment: This works, even with values without parenthesis. The query is a bit ugly and I'm already thinking of adding a new column. However, this answers this particular problem so far. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/453d52/1

Comment: I agree. If you can influence the db structure, explode this field into 2 parts...